# Imprimir todos los elementos de un struct con una unión

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, union

Estoy intentando imprimir el contenido de una estructura con una unión de tipo long, pero no encuentro la manera. La estructura, la unión y algunas cosas más me vienen de plantilla, no lo puedo cambiar. El funcionamiento del programa es el siguiente:

Fuente: pixelfc.c
Programa USO DE LOS CAMPOS DE BITS
Descripci�n: Un programa recibe un long que describe un PixelFC. El byte m�s significativo del entero es el canal Alfa; el siguiente es el color Rojo, el siguiente es el color Verde y el siguiente es el color Azul (el byte menos significativo).

Se pide construir un programa que haga lo siguiente:

- Poner todos los canales del PixelFC a 0.
- Poner a 1 el bit menos significativo del canal Alfa.
- Poner a 1 todo el canal Azul.
- Poner a 0 el bit m�s significativo del canal Azul.
- Determinar el valor del cuarto bit del canal Verde.
- Determinar el valor del quinto bit del canal Azul.

`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct TreintaydosBits {
unsigned bit0  : 1 ;
unsigned bit1  : 1 ;
unsigned bit2  : 1 ;
unsigned bit3  : 1 ;
unsigned bit4  : 1 ;
unsigned bit5  : 1 ;
unsigned bit6  : 1 ;
unsigned bit7  : 1 ;
unsigned bit8  : 1 ;
unsigned bit9  : 1 ;
unsigned bit10 : 1 ;
unsigned bit11 : 1 ;
unsigned bit12 : 1 ;
unsigned bit13 : 1 ;
unsigned bit14 : 1 ;
unsigned bit15 : 1 ;
unsigned bit16 : 1 ;
unsigned bit17 : 1 ;
unsigned bit18 : 1 ;
unsigned bit19 : 1 ;
unsigned bit20 : 1 ;
unsigned bit21 : 1 ;
unsigned bit22 : 1 ;
unsigned bit23 : 1 ;
unsigned bit24 : 1 ;
unsigned bit25 : 1 ;
unsigned bit26 : 1 ;
unsigned bit27 : 1 ;
unsigned bit28 : 1 ;
unsigned bit29 : 1 ;
unsigned bit30 : 1 ;
unsigned bit31 : 1 ;
} TreintaydosBits;


typedef union CuatroBytes {
long            n;
TreintaydosBits b;
} CuatroBytes;

void ImprimeBitsdePixelfc (long);

int main (void)
{
int i;
CuatroBytes pixelfc;

pixelfc.n = 0;

printf("\nTodos los bits del pixelfc puestos a 0\n");
ImprimeBitsdePixelfc(pixelfc.n);
printf("\n");


printf("\nPoner a 1 el bit menos significativo del canal Alfa (bit 24)\n");
pixelfc.b.bit24=1;
ImprimeBitsdePixelfc(pixelfc.n);


printf("\n\nPoner todo el canal Azul a 1\n");
pixelfc.b.bit0=1;
pixelfc.b.bit1=1;
pixelfc.b.bit2=1;
pixelfc.b.bit3=1;
pixelfc.b.bit4=1;
pixelfc.b.bit5=1;
pixelfc.b.bit6=1;
pixelfc.b.bit7=1;
ImprimeBitsdePixelfc(pixelfc.n);

printf("\n\nPoner bit mas significativo canal Azul a 0 (bit 7)\n");
pixelfc.b.bit7=0;
ImprimeBitsdePixelfc(pixelfc.n);
   

printf("\n\nEl cuarto bit del canal Verde vale: %d",pixelfc.b.bit11);
printf("\nEl quinto bit del canal Azul vale: %d",pixelfc.b.bit4);   

printf("\n"); 
return 0;
}

void ImprimeBitsdePixelfc (long nump)
{
printf("+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+");printf("\n");
printf("|       A L F A         |         R O J O       |      V E R D E        |      A Z U L          |");printf("\n");
printf("+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+");printf("\n");

//Aqui tengo que imprimir los bits pero he probado de varias maneras y no lo consigo.
}
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es simple, puedes imprimir manualmente uno por uno todos los bits del campo de bits, es decir *bit0, bit1, bit2...* y así sucesivamente.

Otra solución es utilizar operadores de bits sobre la variable de tipo **long** llamada *n*, para acceder a cada bit individual y obtener su valor.

Ejemplo:

```
int x = 4;
int y = (x & (1 << 0)) ?1 :0; //obtiene el valor del primer bit (el menos significativo)
int z = (x & (1 << 2)) ?1 :0; //obtiene el valor del tercer bit
```

Mediante un bucle y una variable auxiliar que indique el número de bit al cual deseas acceder, puede automatizar este proceso para que no tengas que hacerlo bit por bit.

Ejemplo:

```
const int FUENTE = 1704; 
unsigned int mascara = (1 << ((sizeof(int) * 8u) - 1u));

do{
    printf("%c", (FUENTE & mascara) ?'1' :'0');
    mascara >>= 1u;
}while(mascara != 0u);
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).